# Parsing YouTube video name

Tags: python

I want to parse YouTube video name

I use libraries(requests and BeautifulSoup4)

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_Gto4lAV58'

And I wrote this

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
tmp = soup.findAll('span', class_='style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer')
print(tmp)
```

Output:
[]

If I try

```
print(soup.text)
```

I will get a solve
But why soup.text, if it should be print(tmp)?

Comment: try this https://pytube.io/en/latest/

Comment: This question has been asked _hundreds_ of times on Stack Overflow, and a little basic [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will show you the problem. Try to inspect the contents of `data`. Do you see the html for the page you see in the browser?

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi
if i try 
`print(soup)` 
i will get a weird ending of HTML code which does not match the html code on the utube

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytube

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_Gto4lAV58'

yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
print(yt.title)
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/pytube/